# Fedora 26 hangs on reboot

Tags: linux, fedora, linux-kernel

I'm using fedora 26 and i keep getting these weird hangs on reboot, they are not consistent (I can reboot 20 times and it would work fine, and reboot 20 times again and it will hang).

The last message im getting is

> nfsd last server has exited flushing export cache

I've tried a few things while trying to debug it - Disabled nfs, Disabled watchdog, different grub entries, all without any success.

I'm working on Supermicro x9 and x10.

Did any of you encounter such a problem with fedora 26? (Needless to say it only happens with that version, all other fedora's works fine and Redhat/Centos etc).

Comment: What is the kernel version you are booting? You said it doesn't happen with other distros. Does this mean you have reinstalled multiple times and this is a fresh install?

Comment: the kernel version is 4.15.3-200. I have installed multiple times for debug purposes ofcourse. I have also tried upgrading the kernel itself to the newer version whice is 4.20 i think, still doesnt work sadly.

Comment: But I assume that happens only after you add an NFS mount to your /etc/fstab. So can you please edit your question adding the exact line you have in your /etc/fstab ?

Comment: My fstab only has the system partition listed. And also i did mention did i tried disabling nfs all together to see if that's the issue.